# Get first value from series of dictionaries

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas series `orders['customer']` that looks like this:

```
0      {'id': 454543543533, 'email': 'aaaaaa@gmail.com...
1      {'id': 437890767654, 'email': 'bbbbbbbb@mail.com...
2      {'id': 534764345453, 'email': 'ccccccccc@mail.com..
3      {'id': 345436564353, 'email': None, 'accepts_m....
4      {'id': 671341215803, 'email': None, 'accepts_m...
5      {'id': 671317065787, 'email': None, 'accepts_m...
```

I would like to iterate over the rows of this series and get the first element for each dictionary (`id`). Moreover I would like to substitute the values in the series with only the id.

I tried many different solutions, last this one, but I cannot make this thing work:

```
for i in range(len(orders_df['customer'].values.tolist())):
    orders_df['customer'] = orders_df['customer'].values.tolist()[i]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lambda` function with [`get`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041421) for match value if dictionary with key `id` else return default value, here `0`:

```
orders_df = pd.DataFrame({'customer':[{'id': 454543543533, 'email': 'fdgr@gmail.com'}, 
                                      {'id': 437890767654, 'email': 'ereffewf@mail.com'},
                                      {'email': 'ereffewf@mail.com'}]})
print (orders_df)
                                            customer
0    {'id': 454543543533, 'email': 'fdgr@gmail.com'}
1  {'id': 437890767654, 'email': 'ereffewf@mail.c...
2                     {'email': 'ereffewf@mail.com'}

orders_df['customer'] = orders_df['customer'].apply(lambda x: x.get('id', 0))
```

Or:

```
orders_df['customer'] = [x.get('id', 0) for x in orders_df['customer']]
```

---

```
print (orders_df)
       customer
0  454543543533
1  437890767654
2             0
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, could you explain me a bit how this works?

Comment: @roberto.sannazzaro - Sure, it working because in `Series` are dictionaries and need select `id`, also better is use `get` because if not match (in some row is no `id`) it return None